# How to handle errors with async in a Python loop?

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm using the Etherscan API to collect the dates of the last tx sent from many addresses. I made Python loop to do this. The code you can see below

```py
from datetime import datetime
from etherscan import Etherscan
import csv
import sys
import time

# etherscan api
eth = Etherscan("YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API") # key in quotation marks

# import csv
with open('input/wallets.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file) # drop header
    wallets = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]

# loop
for walletaddress in wallets:
    # parse json
    my_list = eth.get_normal_txs_by_address(address=(walletaddress), startblock="8200000", endblock="18998125", sort="srt")
    des_ind = my_list[-1]
    # convert timestamp to date
    ts = int(des_ind['timeStamp'])
    print(walletaddress + ',' + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    print(walletaddress + ',' + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), file=open(('output/output.csv'), mode='a', encoding="utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.2) # Sleep for 0.2 seconds
```

Everything works fine until I face a wallet that has no transactions sent. I'll get the error below:

```
$ python3 main.py
0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98,2019-07-25 00:55:39
0x201f981aa5fcf15e5c8305448614b5e5fb9f195d,2023-12-20 05:46:23
0x5094ec3773ac3122b70e4c93295f8126862ff71d,2024-01-11 19:11:11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/scrape/ETH/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    my_list = eth.get_normal_txs_by_address(address=(walletaddress), startblock="8200000", endblock="18998125", sort="srt")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/etherscan/etherscan.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return parser.parse(r)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/etherscan/utils/parsing.py", line 12, in parse
    assert status, f"{result} -- {message}"
AssertionError: [] -- No transactions found
```

input of wallets.csv

> address
> 0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98
> 0x201f981aa5fcf15e5c8305448614b5e5fb9f195d
> 0x5094ec3773ac3122b70e4c93295f8126862ff71d
> 0xECf92DA001E4a0AE9bC703B21c154f0f6B1515E9

I read somewhere I could use async to handle the errors, since I don't want my loop to break. I tried something with the following lines:

```
async with Etherscan("YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API") as eth:
    for walletaddress in wallets:
        return await eth.get_normal_txs_by_address(address=(walletaddress), 
            startblock="8200000", endblock="18998125", sort="srt")
except Exception as E:
    if str(E) == '[] -- No transactions found':
       return []
    else:
       print(f'Cannot request history from {startblock} to {endblock} due to {E}')
```

I'm spinning my head around it almost the whole day. I can't get it to work with my code. The few answers I saw are different loops than mine. I think an answer on this question would learn others how to handle errors in similar loops.

How to handle the error above so my loop continues and don't break? Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Just use a `try..except` around the method call to catch expected exceptions…‽

Comment: If Etherscan doesn't provide an async API variant, this won't help. Try to enclose the `get_normal_txs_by_address` in a try-except-block instead. Be sure to check in the except part that the particular exception was raised and reraise the exception otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try using `try` and `except` inside the loop and also adding `aiohttp` functionality and didn't get the error anymore. See if it's doing the job for you too:

```
pip install aiohttp
```

And some tweaks on the code like:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import aiohttp
import csv

async def fetch_transactions(session, eth, walletaddress):
    try:
        async with session.get(
            f"https://api.etherscan.io/api",
            params={
                "module": "account",
                "action": "txlist",
                "address": walletaddress,
                "startblock": "8200000",
                "endblock": "18998125",
                "sort": "asc",
                "apikey": eth.api_key,
            },
        ) as response:
            data = await response.json()
            my_list = data.get("result", [])
            des_ind = my_list[-1]
            ts = int(des_ind['timeStamp'])
            print(walletaddress + ',' + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            print(walletaddress + ',' + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), file=open(('output/output.csv'), mode='a', encoding="utf-8"))
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        if str(e) == '[]':
            print(f"No transactions found for {walletaddress}")
            return False
        else:
            print(f'Cannot request history for {walletaddress} due to {e}')
            return False

async def main():
    # etherscan api
    class Etherscan:
        def __init__(self, api_key):
            self.api_key = api_key

    eth = Etherscan("YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API")

    # import csv
    with open('input/wallets.csv', 'r') as file:
        next(file, None)  # drop header
        wallets = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [fetch_transactions(session, eth, walletaddress) for walletaddress in wallets]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        # Handle results as needed
        print("Script completed. Results:", results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Of course, due to the empty test env I'm getting:

```
Script completed. Results: []
```

But, on a complete software with real dataset should return some data if matched.